# Django registration redux form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Me gustaría saber como puedo editar el estilo de mi formulario, no quiero que aparezca todo de golpe, utilizo `form|crispy` para llamar al formulario.
También estoy utilizando `django registration redux`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que por ejemplo en los `<input>` poner un `placeholder`? También quiero quitar las `label` del formulario.

Este es mi template `login.html`:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form|crispy }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Iniciar sesion' %}" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p>{% trans "Has olvidado tu contrasena" %}? <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Restablecer" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "No tienes cuenta" %}? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Registrarte" %}</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, eso no lo haces en la plantilla, sino en la definición del formulario.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente fragmento, establecemos el `placeholder` y ocultamos las etiquetas en el formulario `ProductividadForm`

```
class ProductividadForm(forms.Form):
     modulo = forms.CharField(max_length = 80, required=True)

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('modulo', placeholder="Escribe la clave del MAC"),
        )
        self.helper. form_show_labels = False
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(data, files, **kwargs)
```

Consulta la documentación sobre [`FromHelper`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html#bootstrap-3-helper-attributes).

Comment: He probado con tu código, poniéndolo en 'views.py' y después llamandolo en 'login.html' pero no me aparece el formulario, llamándolo así '{{ ProductividadForm|crispy }}